# How to get the JSON value from Alarmofire and popup in tabular format?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to get the value from the API in swift and display the response in Controller. I have created the table and I am getting the response from API using Alarmofire. My Question is How to use the Success response of Alarmofire and display in Array. My code is here :

```
 class NotificationHistory : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

let urlStringChecking = "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/uhf/getnotification.php"

func GetNotificationHistory(completionHandler: @escaping (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    getNotifiction(completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

func getNotifiction(completionHandler: @escaping (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()){
    Alamofire.request(urlStringChecking,method: .get)
        .responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            let list = response.result.value;
            completionHandler(list as AnyObject, nil)
        case .failure( _):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }
}


let list = self.GetNotificationHistory(); // If I get success list here then my problem is solved but I am getting an error.
```

ERROR: Value of type '(NotificationHistory) -> () -> (NotificationHistory)' has no member 'list'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(list.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier = "NotificationCell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell!.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Notification History Loaded")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
 }
```

I am very new to Swift. Thanks

Comment: An error? What error? Where is called `GetNotificationHistory`? How is it called?

Comment: check the comment line `let list = list;` here i want that data

Comment: Too few information, but you need to initialize ‘list’ and use self.list in closure part of your ‘getNotificationHistory()’ . Please attach your errors for more clarity.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle json data use `SwiftyJSON` install this third party library using `cocoapods`

First declare your `list` as variable inside `NotificationHistory` class as

```
var list = [[String: AnyObject]]()
```

Add this code to your completion handler `getNotifiction` now your code look like this

```
func getNotifiction(completionHandler: @escaping (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()){
        Alamofire.request(urlStringChecking,method: .get)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    if ((response.result.value) != nil){
                        let jsonData = JSON(response.result.value!)

                        if let mydata = jsonData["list"].arrayObject {
                            self.list = mydata as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        completionHandler(self.list, nil) 
                    }
                case .failure( _):
                    print(response.result.error as Any)
                }
        }
    }
```

And to call this function write `self.GetNotificationHistory()` inside your `viewDidLoad()`

This time we have proper data in `list` variable, now it's time to implement new code in `tableview`

No need to change here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}
```

Need some changes in your code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier = "NotificationCell"

    let newListValue = list[indexPath.row] // assign new values in diff variable

    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell!.textLabel?.text = newListValue[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = newListValue[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell!
}
```

`response.result.value` contain simple array to treat it as JSON we can either use it as

`response.result.value as? [[String:String]]`

or your can use SwiftyJSON

: D

Comment: Thanks!! I am still getting an error tableView func -> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'Int' in cell!.textLabel?.text = newListValue[indexPath.row]

Comment: I forgot to add something in my code try this `cell!.textLabel?.text = newListValue[indexPath.row] as? String`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
let list = self.GetNotificationHistory();
```

GetNotificationHistory makes an asynchronous request and does not return anything. You should set list to your value when you get the response from the server and then reload your tableView.

If list is supposed to be an array of strings, replace `let list = self.GetNotificationHistory()` with:

var list = String

Change your getNotification method to:

```
func getNotifiction(completionHandler: @escaping ([String]?, NSError?) -> ()){
    Alamofire.request(urlStringChecking,method: .get)
        .responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            if let list = response.result.value as? [String] {
               self.list = list
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            completionHandler(self.list, nil)
        case .failure( _):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

And then call `self.GetNotificationHistory()` in your viewDidLoad.